# Is there a way to send CoAP commands using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, coap

I was just wondering if there was a way to send CoAP queries in the browser (using JavaScript?), but not using node.js.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not directly possible. Web browsers do not provide any JavaScript API for UDP sockets for security reasons.

If you need an in-browser app to communicate to a device via a CoAP interface, you may need to provide an intermediary service. For example, you could create a web service that is accessible via HTTP, and acts as a translator to CoAP.

Note that [node.js does support UDP connections](http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html), and could be used to send CoAP messages. However, it is a server-side technology, and cannot be used in the browser. It could be used to build such a translator service; but would not be required.

Also, it appears that "Chrome Apps", which are based on HTML5 and JavaScript, but are distinctly different from web pages, do have access to [UDP Sockets](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible when using [CoAP over TCP/IP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bormann-core-coap-tcp-00) or a [CoAP-HTTP proxy](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-core-http-mapping-04), like [Californium](https://github.com/eclipse/californium/blob/master/cf-proxy/src/main/java/org/eclipse/californium/examples/ExampleCrossProxy.java), [jCoAP](https://code.google.com/p/jcoap/), [SmartServiceProxy](https://github.com/ict-spitfire/smart-service-proxy/) or [Squid with CoAP-HTTP](http://telecom.dei.unipd.it/pages/read/90/).

There is also a partial JavaScript implementation of CoAP - [JSCoAP](https://code.google.com/p/jscoap/).

Comment: is there any example for `JSCoAP` ?. I'm searching how to implement and use it in webpage.

Comment: @LukyBoy-KU Here you go: I have written the [JSCoAP API Reference with an Example](https://github.com/jdeblese/jscoap/wiki/API).

Comment: @nuitech please help me, I tried including JSCOAP in my html page. and then using javascript when I call this method with my coap url nothing happen.
`var buffer = serialize(message, "coap://[aaaa::c30c:0:0:2]:5683/sensor/temperature");`
please help me, i want to do AJAX call using CoAP URL which returns me response. I tried with FireFox Copper Addon and this URL works fine. but I want in AJAX call

Comment: You should contact the JSCoAP library owner Jan-willem De Bleser.